# unable to get my telerik menu to work on ASP

Tags: css, asp.net, telerik

right i've read so many threads on how to implement a custom skin for a telerik menu onto my webpage I know some of you will not know what im talking about but im desperate for help this is what I currently have coded.

In my web config I have:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="Telerik.Skin" value="Glow2"/>
 <add key="Telerik.EnableEmbeddedSkins" value="false"/>
 <add key="Telerik.EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet" value="false"/>
 <add key="Telerik.ScriptManager.TelerikCdn" value="Disabled" />
 <add key="Telerik.StyleSheetManager.TelerikCdn" value="Disabled" />
</appSettings>
```

in my site master I have

```
<link href="Skins/Glow2/Menu.Glow2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and for my menu code I use:

```
<li>
 <asp:LoginView ID="SysAdminLV" runat="server">
 <RoleGroups>
 <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Masters">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <telerik:RadMenu ID="SysAMenu" runat="server" Skin="Glow2">
 <Items>
 <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="Sys Admin" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">
 <Items>
 <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="Create User" NavigateUrl="~/Staff/Masters/New_User.aspx"></telerik:RadMenuItem>
 <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="Manage Users" NavigateUrl="~/Staff/Masters/Manage_Users.aspx"></telerik:RadMenuItem>
 </Items>
 </telerik:RadMenuItem>
 </Items>
 </telerik:RadMenu>
 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:RoleGroup>
 </RoleGroups>
 </asp:LoginView>
 </li>
```

Now my custom skin is called Glow2 because I made very little changes to the "Glow" skin, im not getting an error or anything the page loads fine its just the links that I have do not pull through the syling from the Glow2 Skin. attached is what the page looks like when loaded.my "home" and "Sysadmin" links are telerik the rest are coded through CSS at the moment.

Comment: You have too many run-on sentences which are hard to read. Does your code work with Telerik Grow Skin before making your own skin?

Comment: yes my code works fine if I take out and replace Glow2 with Glow           <add key="Telerik.Skin" value="Glow2"/>
 <add key="Telerik.EnableEmbeddedSkins" value="false"/>
 <add key="Telerik.EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet" value="false"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to change the skin, keep the base stylesheets:

```
<add key="Telerik.EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet" value="true"/>
```

because they provide some core metrics that all skins use, including custom ones: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/controlling-visual-appearance/how-skins-work.